# How to check for double checkbox IsChecked in if statement ? C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, checkbox

How can I check for 2 or more checkBox IsChecked values inside single if statement in WPF C# ? I am trying to do like this but its not working.

```
 if ((symbols_cb.IsChecked ?? true) && (digits_cb.IsChecked ?? true))
 {
        MessageBox.Show("Check - Yes it is selected.");
 }
```

Here **symbols_cb** and **digits_cb** are check box and I want a message to be displayed while both the checkbox has been selected.

Comment: Where is that code running? It needs to be running in some code that is triggered when the checkboxes change state.

Comment: Why not `if ((symbols_cb.IsChecked) && (digits_cb.IsChecked))` ?

Comment: What means "its not working"?

Comment: try `?? false` to exclude their undefined state

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah I have written the same thing using && operator

Comment: @TimSchmelter I mean control is not inside this loop rather than its skipping this code and moving to other condition

Comment: @Baldrick This piece of code is triggering on click of button. Full working is like this:    if (symbols_cb.IsChecked ?? true)
                {
                     MessageBox.Show("Check - ONLY SYMBOLS  is selected.");
                }
                else
            if ((symbols_cb.IsChecked ?? true) && (digits_cb.IsChecked ?? true))
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("Check - Yes it is selected.");

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer:

```
if ((symbols_cb.IsChecked ?? false) && (digits_cb.IsChecked ?? false))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check - Yes it is selected.");
}
```

Comment: it's what I've already suggested :-) The message box should be "they are both selected"

Comment: While this might be more appropriate if OP wants to exclude undefined state, it does't solve the issue: _"control is not inside this loop rather than its skipping this code and moving to other condition "_

Comment: "*its skipping this code*" => don't put this code in the `else if`

Answer (score 1):

the operator `??` not work as you want, this operator chek if left value is null and it is null return rigth value.
you need do this:

```
if (symbols_cb.IsChecked && digits_cb.IsChecked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check - Yes it is selected.");
}
```

Edit: i did´t know that in WPF isChecked return `bool?`. try check value after check if IsChecked has value:

```
if (symbols_cb.IsChecked.HasValue ?? symbols_cb.IsChecked : false   &&
    digits_cb.IsChecked.HasValue ?? digits_cb.IsChecked : false )
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check - Yes it is selected.");
}
```

Comment: In WPF CheckBoxes' [`IsChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) property is a `bool?`. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: `IsChecked` is `bool?` not `bool`: you can't put that in the `if` condition

Comment: @Giulio So how can write a statement to check if 2 checkbox are selected or not ? If both are selected then display some message otherwise something else ?

Answer (score 1):

if this is your View:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Name="symbols_cb" Checked="checkBox_CheckedChanged" Unchecked="checkBox_CheckedChanged" />
    <CheckBox Name="digits_cb" Checked="checkBox_CheckedChanged" Unchecked="checkBox_CheckedChanged"/>
</StackPanel>
```

you can handle the events in the following method:

```
    private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((symbols_cb.IsChecked == true) && (digits_cb.IsChecked == true))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check - Yes it is selected.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Giulio: sure, if you use the `==` operator, this is the same as `if ((symbols_cb.IsChecked ?? false) && (digits_cb.IsChecked ?? false))...`